# Windows8 Scrolling like in weather app

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I have layout as described below:

```
<ScrollViewer>
  <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
     <!-- ... -->
     <ScrollViewer>
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
             <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                   <StackPanel ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"  Orientation="Vertical" />
             </ItemsPanelTemplate>
         </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel> 
     </ScrollViewer>

      <!-- ... -->
  </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

And I would like to achieve that effect that is present in weather app.

In my application, when you're scrolling horizontaly using mouse wheel, when pointer gets over ItemsControl it immediately starts scrolling verticaly wheras in weather application there's fluent horizontal scrolling effect and scrolling verticaly begins when there's some time hover that vertical collection.

Is that behaviour somewhere implemented by default?.

Szymon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, the guideline is that introducing vertical scrolling in a horizontally scrolling repeater is a bad idea. I think you should NOT consider Weather (or any standard Windows 8 app) as a model to emulate. Most of them violate the guidelines in some of the worst ways.

The Weather app accomplishes what you are asking based on the current mouse placement, the motion of the grid, and control with focus. That's a complex way of saying, some developer dreamed up a solution to help make their UI as confusing to the user as possible.

Please, don't.

Answer (score 0):

What I think they do in order to achieve that effect is this:

If the mouse is over the vertical list for a while, they deactivate the horizontal scroll and activate the vertical one. Once the mouse moved outside the list, they switch back (deactivate the vertical scroll and activate the horizontal scroll).

I have not tested this to see if this works, but I think it should.